# Get the cell value from cellClick in ObjectListView's TreeListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

When I use the treeListView cellClick Event:

```
private void treeListView_CellClick(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellClickEventArgs e)
```

Using "CellClickEventArgs e", how can I find the current value (lets assume it is an Int32) of this specific cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
    private void treeListView1_CellClick(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = e.SubItem.ModelValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `CellClickEventArgs` contains property that indicate `Index` of cell. Try to get it and then grab cell from `treeListView` by index.

Comment: I cannot find any "grabCell" or similar method to do this!