# ObjectListView get value of a specific column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview, objectlistview

I am using C # and ObjectListView, need to get the value of the row and column where specific clicked.

Example: Get the value of the clicked row, column 3.

How can I do this through CellClick?

```
private void treeListView1_CellClick(object sender, CellClickEventArgs e)
{
   ???
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it was the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842238/get-the-cell-value-from-cellclick-in-objectlistviews-treelistview

Comment: I would like to get only the value of column 3, regardless of where I clicked. How would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to get only the value of column 3, regardless of where I clicked.

```
private void objectListView1_CellClick(object sender, CellClickEventArgs e) {
    // check if it is the column of interest
    if (e.Column == olvColumn3) {
        // method 1: just get the value from the objectListView1 cell, 
        // this potentially requires casting ModelValue to the correct type which can be error prone if the type changes
        object value = e.SubItem.ModelValue;

        // method 2: since you "know" what property of your underlying model is displayed in column 3,
        // you should retrieve it directly from the model object
        MyModel modelObject = (MyModel)e.Model;
        string value2 = modelObject.ValueThatBelongsToColumn3;
    }
}
```